# Notify me when somebody elses question is answered (If I check a box on their question)

Tags: feature-request, notifications

I noticed you can be notified of questions that you own, but you can't really be notified when other interesting questions are asked. I know you can star a question, but that's sort of manual work (which us programmers tend to find a way to automate :)

Comment: You know you can also subscribe to each question's feed right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to reduce the load on the server, and avoid a situation where thousands of mail are sent an hour, subscribing to a question is purposefully limited to the person who asked the question.  The RSS feed is more suitable for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Each question has its own RSS feed for you to track answers to. It's in the form:

> https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/{questionID}

Which will update in your feed reader of choice any new answers posted.

Comment: Using a service like FeedMyInbox ( http://www.feedmyinbox.com/ ) will send an email as and when the feed gets updated, if email notifications are so desperately needed.