# Get a notification when new answers are added to other people's question

Tags: feature-request, support, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notify me when somebody elses question is answered (If I check a box on their question)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37397/notify-me-when-somebody-elses-question-is-answered-if-i-check-a-box-on-their-qu)
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Is there a way to get a notification (either email or via the "stack exchange" drop-down/inbox), when a new answer was added to a question (which was asked by another user)?

I found this question: [Notify me of answers to other people's questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76002/notify-me-of-answers-to-other-peoples-questions), but this is related to the envelope icon which no longer exists.

Comment: @Cody: I have never seen that. Is it described somewhere?

Comment: Hmm, maybe here: [What does a small asterisk in the favorites tab in my user profile mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88127/what-does-a-small-asterisk-in-the-favorites-tab-in-my-user-profile-mean) There are [lots of questions about favorites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/favorites), though, including disagreements about how the UI should work, what they should be used for, and how we should be notified regarding them.

Comment: OK, I see it - it's that blue "[*]" which you don't notice if you don't know what it is :-)

Comment: This isn't necessarily about favourite questions. I think it would be good to have an option for notifications to the SE inbox (off by default obviously) for questions that you actively wanted to be kept informed on without having to go into your profile page to check for updates.

Comment: More related questions: [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/), [What is the best way to be notified when a specific question (not my own) is answered?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88468/), [Can more of the functionality of the old envelope be added to the new drop-down menu?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83286/)