# Notify me when a question receives an answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Sometines I find questions that I am interested in but haven't received an answer yet. I would like to 'subscribe' to this question and be notified by email when it receives an answer.

This is different from the *favorite* button, where you should come back another day to see if tge favorited question has received any answer.

You can even have some types or categories of subscription like:

- notify me when it receives *any* answer
- notify me when the OP selects an *accepted answer*

I think this is a good feature to have that will increase the overall user experience of a user in any SE sites.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37397/notify-me-when-somebody-elses-question-is-answered-if-i-check-a-box-on-their-qu

Comment: @random ok duplicate, next thing to do is to improve SE search engine as it didn't appear those :)

Comment: I find that using the ask a question title search is better at turning up dupes than the actual search bar... I usually check both.